# Magento 1.9 - Sweet Tooth - Applying reward points to a quote

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, reward-points

We currently use sweet tooth extension.

I am currently creating a quote in PHP which works as expected. My issue is applying an amount of Loyalty/Reward Points.

I know that the variable $loyalty_points_spent is working correctly, my problem is the following couple of lines do not apply the points to the quote.

```
if (isset($loyalty_points_spent) && !is_null($loyalty_points_spent)){
    $quote->setUseRewardPoints($loyalty_points_spent);
}
```

This is all of my code which currently creates a quote.

```
// initial vars
$productids = $order_details['products'];
$websiteId = $order_details['ids']['website_id'];
$store = $order_details['ids']['store_id'];
$loyalty_points_spent = $order_details['payment']['points_used'];
// Start New Sales Order Quote
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store);
// Set points
if (isset($loyalty_points_spent) && !is_null($loyalty_points_spent)){
    $quote->setUseRewardPoints($loyalty_points_spent);
}
// Set Sales Order Quote Currency
$quote->setBaseCurrencyCode($order_details['payment']['currency']);
$quote->setQuoteCurrencyCode($order_details['payment']['currency']);
$quote->setCurrency($order_details['payment']['currency']);
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
        ->loadByEmail($order_details['customer']['email']);
if ($customer->getId() == "") {
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname($order_details['customer']['firstname'])
            ->setLastname($order_details['customer']['flastname'])
            ->setEmail($order_details['customer']['email']);
    $customer->save();
}
// Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);
// Configure Notification
$quote->setSendCconfirmation(1);
// Set products
foreach ($productids as $id)
{
    $product_qty = $order_details['product_quantities'][$id];
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' => $product_qty)));
}
// Set Sales Order Billing Address
$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(array(
    'customer_address_id' => $order_details['billing']['id'],
    'prefix' => $order_details['billing']['prefix'],
    'firstname' => $order_details['billing']['firstname'],
    'middlename' => $order_details['billing']['middlename'],
    'lastname' => $order_details['billing']['lastname'],
    'suffix' => $order_details['billing']['suffix'],
    'company' => '',
    'street' => $order_details['billing']['street'],
    'city' => $order_details['billing']['city'],
    'country_id' => $order_details['billing']['country'],
    'region' => 'UP',
    'postcode' => $order_details['billing']['postcode'],
    'telephone' => '78676789',
    'fax' => 'gghlhu',
    'vat_id' => '',
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
        ));
// Set Sales Order Shipping Address
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(array(
    'customer_address_id' => $order_details['billing']['id'],
    'prefix' => $order_details['shipping']['prefix'],
    'firstname' => $order_details['shipping']['firstname'],
    'middlename' => $order_details['shipping']['middlename'],
    'lastname' => $order_details['shipping']['lastname'],
    'suffix' => $order_details['shipping']['suffix'],
    'company' => '',
    'street' => $order_details['shipping']['street'],
    'city' => $order_details['shipping']['city'],
    'country_id' => $order_details['shipping']['country'],
    'region' => 'UP',
    'postcode' => $order_details['shipping']['postcode'],
    'telephone' => '78676789',
    'fax' => 'gghlhu',
    'vat_id' => '',
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
        ));
// Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectTotals()
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('royalmail_UK_CONFIRMED_ROYAL_MAIL_SIGNED_FOR_FIRST_CLASS_SMALL_PARCEL')
        ->setPaymentMethod($pmethod);
// Set Sales Order Payment
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => $pmethod));
// Collect Totals & Save Quote
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
return $quote;
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue using the following:

**// Get points used from order**

```
$order->getPointsUsed($orderId);
```

**// Set points used on quote and billingAddress**

```
$quote->setPointsSpending($loyalty_points_used);
$billingAddress->setPointsSpending($loyalty_points_used);
```

**// Remove points from user's account**

```
$transfer = Mage::getModel('rewards/transfer');
$transfer->setId(null)
                ->setCurrencyId("1")
                ->setQuantity($points)
                ->setComments(Mage::getStoreConfig('rewards/transferComments/orderSpent'))
                ->setRuleId("1")
                ->setCustomerId($customerId)
                ->save();
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else trying to programatically use Sweet Tooth Loyalty Points